# HTML element missing and not well formatted in PHP if statement

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have this code in a wordpress custom post type (CPT). Despite all I tried, the font awesome element in the span tag won't show and the css properties are left out

```
$memEmail = the_field('member_email');
if( !empty($memEmail)) { ?>
    echo                        
    '<a href="mailto:#"><span>
         <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>'
         .$memEmail. '</span></a>';     
   <?php }
```

Here is the css

```
span {
    border-top: 1px dotted #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
    padding: 7px 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
}
```

The picture below shows how the final output ought to be without the if statement:

[image: The final output was supposed to be this:]

But the code above output this when in if statement:

[image]

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, please update your code to show the output HTML as it is sent by email or seen by the user on the website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference Font Awesome in your HTML page or if you are sending an email, it needs to be included in the email HTML. You can try adding this CDN although there are others as well:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css
```

Code to add to HTML would be:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

If Font Awesome isn't referenced correctly, the icon will not show.

Answer (score 0):

Your echo needs to be included in your php code.
You closed the PHP then tried to echo.  Hope it helps

```
$memEmail = the_field('member_email');
if( !empty($memEmail)) { 
echo  '<a href="mailto:#"><span class="class"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>'.$memEmail.'</span></a>'; }
```

Comment: I tried all that, the result is same.
@SteveB Of course I referenced fontawesome. The fontawesome element doesn't show only in the if statement. Without the if statement, it shows fine